# Me aparece un error, el nombre Abrir no se encuentre en el contexto actual

Tags: c#, .net, vscode

estoy empezando con C# copie este codigo de un video turorial de youtube, el tema es que al final del codigo cuando llamo al metodo Abrir de la instancia conexion, El Visual Studio me resalta como error el metodo Abrir, me dice que no se encuentra en el contexto actual y al metodo lo estoy llamando desde la misma clase, no se si ese sera el problema,

`introducir el código aquí`

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace ConexionSqlServer
{

    class Conexionbd
    {
        
        //Cadena de Conexion
        string cadena = "data source = DESKTOP-1EFO5DR; initial catalog = DBCARRITO1; Integrity Security=True";

        public SqlConnection Conectarbd = new SqlConnection();

        //Constructor
        public Conexionbd()
        {
            Conectarbd.ConnectionString = cadena;
        }

        //Metodo para abrir la conexion
        public void Abrir()
        {

            try
            {
                Conectarbd.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("error al abrir BD ", ex.Message);
            }
        }

        //Metodo para cerrar la conexion
        public void Cerrar()
        {
            Conectarbd.Close();
     
        }
        // Luego podremos usarla desde cualquier otro lugar
        Conexionbd conexion = new Conexionbd();

        conexion.Abrir();
       

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Que yo sepa no es posible llamar a una clase dentro de la misma clase y si tratas de abrir un método dentro de la misma clase donde lo estás delcarando solo necesito escribir el método

Abrir();

Answer (score 0):

No es posible llamar una función de esa manera, dentro de una clase se **DECLARAN** variables, propiedades, funciones, etc.. Y no es el sitio para ejecutar funciones. Si lo piensas, es por eso que existe una función "Main" que da inicio al programa, porque no es posible empezar sin nada.

Si tu quieres que tu función se ejecute al instanciar tu clase solo debes colocarla en el constructor

```
public Conexionbd()
{
     Conectarbd.ConnectionString = cadena;
     conexion.Abrir();  //<--- dentro del constructor
}
```

El constructor es lo primero que se ejecuta al instanciar la clase y "es como" la función "Main" de cada clase